# How can I save the same parameters from different for loops?

Tags: r, save

I have a for loop that works in function of `x` and `y`.

So, finally the for loop gives me results like `z`, `a`, `b`.

I want to save `x`, `y` , `z`, `a` and `b` sequentially, changing x and y.

First, I did this to save the first parameters `(x=0.1, y=10)` and its results `("yes", z, a , b)`.

```
saveRDS(paste(x,y,"yes",z,a,b),file=paste("exer.RData"))
readRDS(file="exer.RData")
# [1] 0.2 10 yes 0.675791369732277 -0.52120086986903 0.353252113912809
```

And then, to save the next results, I tried to do this:

```
result<-NULL
result<-c(result,readRDS(file="tfm.RData"))
```

And get this error:

```
Error: object 'result' not found
```

I think that it's necesary to use a for loop and not the above, I tried this:

```
res<-paste(x,y,"yes",z,a,b)
for(i in 1:length(res)){
  saveRDS(i,file=paste0(names(res[i]),".rda"))}
```

I'm new in R, I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you want to save in your loop? ```names(res[i])``` this one gives NULL as result

Comment: I want to save x,y,"yes",z,a,b. Something like this:

Comment: `x       y   yes                 z                                     a                               b      `

Comment: `0.2   10   yes  0.675791369732277   -0.52120086986903   0.353252113912809 `

Comment: ` 0.1 100 yes 0.123486573 -0.4635748354  0.343927464937412809`

Comment: @Triss and so on I will change x , y , z , a or b.

Comment: ```res<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20,yes=rep("yes",10),z=21:30)

res<-apply(res,1,paste,collapse=",")

for(i in 1:length(res))
{
store<-res[i]
saveRDS(store,file=paste(res[i],".rda"))
}
``` not sure whether it is helpful

Comment: Thanks @Triss! This is what I need.